# New Ionic push registering device tokens

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification

I´ve set up all necessary for push notifications described [here](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/).

I am registering the device on startup like:

```
// register for pushio
    $ionicPush.register().then(function(t) {
      return $ionicPush.saveToken(t, {ignore_user:true});
    }).then(function(t) {
      console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
    });
```

The device token is logged "Token saved: xxxxthetokenxxxx".

Now I´m sending push from CURL and the Ionic.io dashboard. The status (checked with CURL) of the message is 200 and no errors. So the push notification is sent:

```
{"meta": {"request_id": "8d9c69ce-b66c-4002-8cb3-f91c57505b0f", "version": "2.0.0-beta.0", "status": 200}, "data": []}
```

But my device isn´t recieving the notification. I think that this is due to the `saveToken()` function. Where is `saveToken()` saving the token?

Does anybody have a clue how to solve this?

UPDATE: 
I´m using this code to send the push:

```
<?php $curl = curl_init();
$token = "mytoken";

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '

  {
  "tokens": "bbc654c496abc2dc42a40941ac944f0a8aeb0d5b227d523e335dbd51b71ed646",
  "profile": "getto",
  "notification": {
      "message": "Hello World!"
  }
  }',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer $token",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
} ?>
```

**EDIT:** The strange thing is, that on Android the device token is not registered.

Comment: You don't have to save token on device, you will have to pass that to API.

Comment: I call $ionicPush.saveToken(). This saves the token to the Ionic database!? And when I send a push from Ionic.io dashboard, this saved token should get passed to the API the ionic.io dashboard uses. Am I right?

Comment: Or do i need to save the token myself? If I try it on device and send a notification to this token the above reply is shown. But no message delivered. I have updated the question with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the service and register your device in your module's run function. You'll need the device token that is registered by the user for sending notification to the user.

```
$ionicPush.init({
  debug: true,
  onNotification: function (notification) {
    console.log('token:', notification.payload);
  },
  onRegister: function (token) {
    console.log('Device Token:', token);
    $ionicPush.saveToken(token); // persist the token in the Ionic Platform
  }
});

$ionicPush.register();
```

Ionic Push lets you create targeted push notifications through the dashboard ([ionic.io](https://apps.ionic.io/apps)). You can also send notifications from the server in the below format.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer API_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "tokens": ["DEVICE_TOKEN"],
        "profile": "PROFILE_TAG",
        "notification": {
                "message": "Hello World!"
        "android": {
                  "title": "Hi User",
                  "message": "An update is available for your App",
                  "payload": {
                        "update": true
                  }
            }
    } }' "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications"
```

Comment: That´s right. Thanks. But where are the tokens saved? And how to retrieve them inside curl? Do i need to save the token myself in an external database?

Comment: You can send targeted notifications to your users with custom messages for individual users and at any time.
Refer https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#summary.


If you want to do any of the above then you have to save the tokens of all the users against their unique ids in any database.


But if your requirement is only to send bulk notification to all your users and only manually, then You can create notifications in the Dashboard by navigating to Push › New Notification.
Refer https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#sending-pushes